# Finding Greatest Common Divisor using LuaLatex

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode, directlua

Here is my code to find Greatest Common Divisor of two positive integers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function gcd(a,b)
    if b ~= 0 then
        return gcd(b, a % b)
    else
        return math.abs(a)
    end
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\findgcd[2]{\directlua{tex.sprint(gcd(#1,#2))}}

\begin{document}
\findgcd{5,10}
\end{document}
```

It throws error. The expected output is simply gcd of 5 and 10. Is % sign in lua code causing the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have defined `\findgcd` with two arguments, but you only supply one:

```
\findgcd{5}{10}
```

will work.

If you want the syntax `\findgcd{5,10}`, then declare it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function gcd(a,b)
    if b ~= 0 then
        return gcd(b, a % b)
    else
        return math.abs(a)
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\findgcd[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(gcd(#1))}}

\begin{document}
\findgcd{5,10}
\end{document}
```

Here's a simple package code, save as `gcd.sty`:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{gcd}[2019/07/22]
\RequirePackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function gcd(a,b)
    if b ~= 0 then
        return gcd(b, a % b)
    else
        return math.abs(a)
    end
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\findgcd[2]{\directlua{tex.sprint(gcd(#1,#2))}}

\endinput
```

Now your document, as soon as `gcd.sty` is in a directory read by the TeX engines, can be

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gcd}

\begin{document}
\findgcd{5}{10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to store this function as a package? I mean something like this. \usepackage{gcd} and with this package \findgcd command will be available to use it anywhere in document.

Comment: @user61681 Yes, write a package and upload it to CTAN.

Comment: Could you share some resources? How to write package for this type of lua functions?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed help. You are great...! Just one last query, though it is out of scope here. I am trying to learn how to write latex macros (own commands, environments etc.). I couldn't find any resources for that. I have programming background    but still find it difficult to learn latex programming. Could you share some resources if you know? Thanks again.

Comment: @user61681 It's best if they're documented.

Comment: If I want to make available file.lua and mypackage.sty files available to all tex documents on my local computer, where should I place these files?  I am working on Windows 7 operating system with miktex installed.